# Python if elif program to calculate wavelength of light

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am working on a Python programming which asks the user for wavelength value and prints a description of the corresponding part of the electromagnetic spectrum, as given in the following table.

```
| Type          | Wavelength             | Frequency                |
|---------------+------------------------+--------------------------|
| Radio Waves   | 10^–3 to 10^–1         | 3 × 10^9 to 3 × 10^11    |
| Microwaves    | 10^–3 to 10^–1         | 3 × 10^9 to 3 × 10^11    |
| Infrared      | 7 × 10^–7 to 10^–3     | 3 × 10^11 to 4 × 10^14   |
| Visible Light | 4 × 10^–7 to 7 × 10^–7 | 4 × 10^14 to 7.5 × 10^14 |
| Ultraviolet   | 10^–8 to 4 × 10^–7     | 7.5 × 10^14 to 3 × 10^16 |
| X-Rays        | 10^–11 to 10^–8        | 3 × 10^16 to 3 × 10^19   |
| Gamma Rays    | < 10^–11               | > 3 × 10^19              |
```

Now I am trying to use multiple if elif statements to get to the result, but somehow I am getting indentation errors and I know I am somewhat incorrect in the entire coding as well. I am a beginner programmer who is learning Python as a starting language(just started a week ago). Here's the code I have been working on. Can someone please kindly help me with the code?

```
wavelength = int(input('Please enter the wavelength...'))

if wavelength > 1E-1:
    frequency < 3E9, Wtype = Radio Waves

elif 1E-3 <= wavelength <= 1E-1:
    3E9 <= frequency <= 3E11, Wtype = Microwaves


elif 7E-7 <= wavelength <= 1E-1:
    3E11 <= frequency <= 4E14, Wtype = Infrared

elif 4E-7 <= wavelength <= 7E-7:
    4E14 <= frequency <= 7.5E14, Wtype = Visible Light

elif 1E-8 <= wavelength <= 4E-7:
    7.5E14 <= frequency <= 3E16, Wtype = Ultraviolet

elif 1E-11 <= wavelength <= 1E-8:
    3E16 <= frequency <= 3E19, Wtype = X-Rays



elif  wavelength <= 1E-11:
    frequency > 3E19, Wtype = Gamma Rays


print('Your wavelength is{0}'.format(Wtype))
```

UPDATE:

I have improvised some on the code.

Ben, thank you for your input. I have improvised on the code per the given requirement. Here it is. No matter what input I put, it gives "Gamma Rays" as the output.

```
while True:
    wavelength = float(input('Please enter the wavelength...'))



    if 1E-3 <= wavelength <= 1E-1:
        Wtype = 'Radio Waves'

    elif 1E-3 <= wavelength <= 1E-1:
        Wtype = 'Microwaves'


    elif 7E-7 <= wavelength <= 1E-1:
        Wtype = 'Infrared'

    elif 4E-7 <= wavelength <= 7E-7:
        Wtype = 'Visible Light'

    elif 1E-8 <= wavelength <= 4E-7:
        Wtype = 'Ultraviolet'

    elif 1E-11 <= wavelength <= 1E-8:
        Wtype = 'X-Rays'

    elif  wavelength >= 1E-11:
        Wtype = 'Gamma Rays'


    print('Your wavelength is {0}'.format(Wtype))
```

Comment: *"somehow I am getting indentation errors"* - yes, *"somehow"*, **because your indentation is wrong**. Consider following an introductory tutorial (e.g. the official one, [2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) or [3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)).

Comment: @Cain indentation is required after an if statement

Comment: 1) `frequency < 3E9,` etc, performs a test on the value of `frequency`, but you don't have a variable with that name, and you don't store the results of those tests, so the code doesn't make sense.  2) `type` is the name of a Python built-in, you shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks Guys....I made some changes to the indentation and changed "type" to Wtype but still no success...

Comment: why do you mention `frequency` in your script at all? Is it input or should it be output computed based on `wavelength` in your case?

Comment: BTW, you can calculate frequency from wavelength and the speed of light.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your code:

1. `3E9 <= frequency <= 3E11, Wtype = Microwaves`; Use `;`, not `,` to separate lines
2. `Wtype = Microwaves`; You never defined `Microwaves`, so that would also throw an error. You have to either make `Microwaves` equal `'Microwaves'`, or more simply just put `Wtype = 'Microwaves'` (Strings must be enclosed in `" "` or `' '`)

I modified your code to where it works:

```
while True:
wavelength = float(input('Please enter the wavelength: '))



if 1E-3 <= wavelength <= 1E-1:
    Wtype = 'Radio Waves'

elif 1E-3 <= wavelength <= 1E-1:
    Wtype = 'Microwaves'


elif 7E-7 <= wavelength <= 1E-1:
    Wtype = 'Infrared'

elif 4E-7 <= wavelength <= 7E-7:
    Wtype = 'Visible Light'

elif 1E-8 <= wavelength <= 4E-7:
    Wtype = 'Ultraviolet'

elif 1E-11 <= wavelength <= 1E-8:
    Wtype = 'X-Rays'

elif  wavelength >= 1E-11:
    Wtype = 'Gamma Rays'


print('Your wavelength is {0}'.format(Wtype))
```

Here's a test run:

```
>>> Please enter the wavelength: 0.8798798789                                                                                                                     
Your wavelength is Gamma Rays                                                                                                                                 
>>> Please enter the wavelength: 0.0000000005                                                                                                                     
Your wavelength is X-Rays                                                                                                                                     
>>> Please enter the wavelength: 1E-8                                                                                                                             
Your wavelength is Ultraviolet                                                                                                                                
>>> Please enter the wavelength: 1E-11                                                                                                                            
Your wavelength is X-Rays                                                                                                                                     
>>> Please enter the wavelength: .00000300000                                                                                                                     
Your wavelength is Infrared                                                                                                                                   
>>> Please enter the wavelength: 3E-7                                                                                                                             
Your wavelength is Ultraviolet                                                                                                                                
>>> Please enter the wavelength: 4E-7                                                                                                                             
Your wavelength is Visible Light
```

Comment: `3E9` is valid syntax for entering a `float` in scientific notation. `3E9` is `3.0*10**9`.